# how to create a folder within a GitHub repository?

Tags: github

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnnIZ.png

how to create a folder within a GitHub repository to solve the above issue, the above problem is because of too many files within the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create it locally, and push it to remote after setting the upstream for your branch.